# Unable to bulk update products after upgrade to 2.4.3

Tags: attributes, upgrade, magento2.4.3

After upgrading my Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3, I cannot bulk update attributes. Clicking the 'Save' button generates an error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\GetSkusByProductIdsCache::execute() must be of the type array, null given, called in public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save/ProcessInventoryPlugin.php on line 99 and defined in public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Model/GetSkusByProductIdsCache.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save/ProcessInventoryPlugin.php(99): Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\GetSkusByProductIdsCache->execute()
#1 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\ProcessInventoryPlugin->afterExecute()
#2 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#3 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#4 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#5 public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#6 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#7 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->___callParent()
#8 public_html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#9 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch()
#10 public_html/app/code/WeltPixel/Backend/Plugin/Utility.php(76): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): WeltPixel\Backend\Plugin\Utility->aroundDispatch()
#12 public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#14 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#15 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#16 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute\Save\Interceptor->dispatch()
#17 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#18 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#19 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#20 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#21 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#22 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#23 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#24 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#25 public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#26 public_html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#27 {main} [] []
```

Can anyone advise how to fix this issue please?

Comment: An update, I have 2 dev sites created from the same live site, both running CE 2.4.3. They were created a few weeks apart. They are identical in almost everyway, 1 site has this problem, the other doesn't. How do I diagnose what is causing this issue?

Comment: Can anyone provide an answer please?